# How to get the smallest child in a box?

Tags: flutter

Consider

```
new ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new RaisedButton(child: const Text('1')),
  ],
)
```

How to make the button occupy only its natural width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider wrapping your `RaisedButton` in a `Row`. In addition to letting the button be its intrinsic width, you can use the `Row` to position the button horizontally using the `mainAxisAlignment` constructor argument. e.g. to right-align the button, use this:

```
          new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  new RaisedButton(
                    child: const Text('1'),
                    onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```